# Format date for the flow:interview finish location

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, finishlocation

I know there are several questions and answers on how to format a date in a Visualforce page, but now I have a more complex one.

I am using a flow in a visualforce page and I need to redirect the user to the edit page of a Task while pre filling the current date in the correct format (with respect to the User's locale). Something like:

```
<flow:interview name="Task_Quote" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/00T/e?&tsk4='&TODAY()}">
```

The above doesn't work because Salesforce complains that & expects a text instead of a date. Using TEXT(TODAY()) will always conert to dd/mm/YYYY which is not always valid

Any other suggestions ?